# Remove Characters such as %,$ from text during post with MVC/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a C# razor page that contains text boxes that are posted back to the server.

In C#, the type of the fields are int, but I would like the user to be able to type '%' into the fields, yet have the page post back an int.  Is this possible?

Currently, I'm filtering out the '%' using JavaScript on the submit action, but the problem is the user is able to see the '%' disappear for half a second before the submit, which is unsightly.  Can I strip out the '%' at some other point?

**Razor**

```
<td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.percentComplete, new { @class = "interactive_editor percent_editor", rows = 1 })</td>
```

**C#**

```
public int percentComplete { get; set; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#submit_page').click(function () {
    percentsToNumbers();
});

function percentsToNumbers() {
    $(".percent_editor").each(function () {
        var originalText = $(this).val();
        var number = originalText.replace('%', '');
        $(this).val(number);
    });
}
```

**Note**
In the past I've created a separate field such as *percentString* for display purposes, that gets converted to a separate *Percent* field after post back.  But if I could just convert it during the page postback process to avoid having two fields in the model that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a hidden field to hold and post back the formatted content? Instead of assigning the replaced value to the text box assign it to the hidden field:

```
function percentsToNumbers() {
    $(".percent_editor").each(function () {
        var originalText = $(this).val();
        var number = originalText.replace('%', '');
        //$(this).val(number);
        $('.percent_editor_hidden').val(number); //Hidden field
    });
}
```

And on the page load bind the same variable to both the text box and hidden field.
Note that if you are using non-ajax post then you have to set the `name` property of the hidden field to match the parameter name in the controller. i.e. `percentComplete`. And have a different name for the text box.

FYI - If you are taking input of a number then you should not have a text area but a text box with a percentage (%) sign beside it so that user can understand that the input should be number. Since you are binding it to an `int` type in the controller.

Comment: Or I supposed the JavaScript could do the work of changing the field to a hidden field and creating another editable field visible to the user.  That seems like a reasonable approach, since I also created some JavaScript to handle the displaying of the percent sign.  Thank you.